# What do the numbers in the eslint terminal output mean?

Tags: javascript, eslint

This is outputted to the terminal when I run Eslint.

`64:7  warning  Use array destructuring`

The 64 I believe is the line number causing the warning on that particular file but what does the 7 mean?

Comment: Numbers like these usually are in the form `vertical line`:`horizontal character count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second number is the column number, the number of spaces over from the start of the line:

[image]